# Breaking up node module code (for a library/api client)

Tags: node.js, module, javascript

I'm writing a node module to consume a REST API for a service. For all intents and purposes we might as well say it's twitter (though it's not).

The API is not small. Over a dozen endpoints. Given that I want to offer convenience methods for each of the endpoints I need to split up the code over multiple files. One file would be far too large.

Right now I am testing the pattern I will outline below, but would appreciate any advice as to other means by which I might break up this code. My goal essentially is to extend the prototype of a single object, but do so using multiple files.

Here's the "model" I'm using so far, but don't think is really a good idea:

TwitterClient.js

```
function TwitterClient(){
  this.foo = "bar";
}

require("fs").readdirSync("./endpoints").forEach(function(file) {
  require("./endpoints/" + file)(TwitterClient);
});

var exports = module.exports = TwitterClient;
```

endpoints/endpointA.js etc

```
module.exports = function(TwitterClient){
  TwitterClient.prototype.someMethod = function(){
    //do things here
  }
}
```

The basic idea obviously is that any file in the endpoints folder is automatically loaded and the TwitterClient is passed in to it, so that it's prototype can be accessed/extended.

I don't plan to stick with this pattern because for some reason it seems like a bad idea to me.

Any suggestions of better patterns are very much appreciated, cheers

Comment: subscribed, but I like your solution (=